# Godaddy Cron Job execute query every 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, .htaccess, cron

The url is `www.example.com/data.php`

My htaccess removes .php so it becomes `www.example.com/data`

I want a query to be executed every 15 minutes.

At first I used AJAX, but this was executing the query on refresh too which isn't what I want.

```
(function grabber() {
   $.ajax({
     url: 'data', 
     complete: function() {
        setTimeout(grabber, 1000 * 60 * 15);
     }
   });
})();
```

I tried reading around and found cron job to be my solution.
I found the area where I can insert a cron job into godaddy but I am not sure what to insert.

I found an example online:

```
00 8,14,18,19,20,21,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/myname/cata/public_html/cron_dup.php >> /cata/tmp/cron_dup.log
```

All my files are in /public_html
Can I just simply enter the full website address www.example.com/data?

Comment: enter the website address where, for what? cron is a job scheduler. it knows NOTHING of websites or php. all it does it run commands at specific times.

Comment: that cron command looks proper. Best way to check is trying it out and see what response you get.

Comment: @MarcB instead of /home/myname/cata/public_html/cron_dup.php, can I put www.example.com/data ? The path currently is not mine, I copied it from an example

Comment: no, because php doesn't know what urls are either. php runs php code. it does not "run urls". if you want to trigger a web-based script, then either your php script does `file_get_Contents('http://...')`, or you just tell cron to do `wget http://...` instead.